# Different wave form of Rs485

Tags: rs485

I have a device in aircraft (DEU). It has a output data to control a light ( diming control). In accordance with aircraft document this data is rs485. But i see a different form of wave in oscilloscope. 
In start edge of possitive signal of data i see a possitive spike (just 20 microseconds) and in start of negative signal of data vise versa.
How can convert this wave to original format?
Have anyone this experience in this data format?

[image]

As you know first waveform is standard rs485. But second signal is my received signal. 
I have not any more information about source signal. And i want decode it by trial and error.
But at first I should convert second signal to original form.

Comment: Please provide a scope trace, or at least a detailed drawing with amplitude and timing. Why is the spike a problem? What is the original format that you want this converted to? What is the format of the dimming data? Is this a dedicated RS485 line, or is it shared with some other functions? If so, what other functions? And what document requires RS485 for light dimming, and why? If you cannot provide a link to the document, provide a quote of the relevant section.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Given the graphs it looks like you can restore the DC levels with some receivers or comparators and a flip-flop. I'll leave the below comments in place for future reference.

Something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzliEf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You could also use a 1/2 74HC74 in place of the cross-coupled gates.

End edit.

Well, one of the most common communication bus configurations on larger aircraft is ARINC429 which has a tristate bipolar RTZ format as you describe. In the high-speed mode it has a 10usec bit time so similar to your description:

[image]

Why are you mucking with this? Usually folks would buy an approved interface device and **not** attempt to directly connect to the aircraft avionics bus. Expensive, but so are approvals and everything else to do with aircraft.

Comment: We are approved company to change aircraft cabin lighting system. And want to study aircraft old system not change this system. And i am sure it is not arinc. It is rs485. But in last output stage of DEU it has a small 1/1 transformer to isulation that couse changing waveform. My q is how can change to original form.

Comment: RS-485 does not have transformers so I guess you need more info from the manufacturer.

Comment: My friend please forget aircraft. I want convert second signal to first signal in above picture. It is my problem.

Comment: Okay it looks like it would be pretty easy with some receivers and an RS flip flop. What voltages? A few volts?